# In Bokeh Timeseries plot, how do I specify line_width?

Tags: python, time-series, bokeh

```
    ts1 = TimeSeries(
        xyvalues1, index='Time', legend=True,
        title="RSSI and PER", tools=TOOLS, xscale='datetime', xlabel = 'time', ylabel='Rx Power (dB)', width = 1800, height = 300)


    ts2 = TimeSeries(
        xyvalues2, index='Time', legend=True,
        title="EVM", tools = TOOLS, xscale='datetime', xlabel = 'time', ylabel='EVM (dB)', width = 1800, height= 300)
    ts2.x_range = ts1.x_range
    ts2.y_range = ts1.y_range
```

In the above code, how do I specify line width for ts1 and ts2?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. As Stack Overflow is not the best place to track improvements and discussions like this I suggest that you open this kind of questions or discussions to the [bokeh mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?hl=en#!forum/bokeh) or [open an issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) at the bokeh github project :-)

The idea of adding support to stile Charts in bokeh.charts interface (like TimeSeries, for instance) have emerged a bit during some of the [first discussions](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1373) regards that interface. But right now (as for bokeh 0.8.2) it's not support yet. I'm sure it can be part of bokeh.charts in a near future but as it's still very experimental we are first focusing on getting that interface "right".

The specific part of the charts that handles renderers creation of charts is not exposed so you can't just tell TimeSeries the line width you want but you can create your own TimeSeries builder and factory function that do what you want. Something like this (:

```
from bokeh.charts._builder import create_and_build
from bokeh.charts.builder.timeseries_builder import TimeSeriesBuilder
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d, GlyphRenderer, Range1d
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Line
from bokeh.charts.utils import chunk, cycle_colors

class CustomTSBuilder(TimeSeriesBuilder):
    def _yield_renderers(self):
        """Use the line glyphs to connect the xy points in the time series.
        Takes reference points from the data loaded at the ColumnDataSource.
        """
        self._duplet = list(chunk(self._attr, 2))
        colors = cycle_colors(self._duplet, self.palette)

        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(self._duplet, start=1):
            glyph = Line(x=x, y=y, line_color=colors[i - 1], line_width=3)
            renderer = GlyphRenderer(data_source=self._source, glyph=glyph)
            self._legends.append((self._groups[i-1], [renderer]))
            yield renderer

def CustomTimeSeries(values, index=None, xscale='datetime', **kws):
    return create_and_build(
        CustomTSBuilder, values, index=index, xscale=xscale, **kws
    )
```

NOTE: Please note that this code works with current release but may not be support in future dev or official releases.